# JUnit Tests with GWT Editor

Tags: gwt, junit, gwt-editors

In my current project we have a gwt clientapplication based on mvp pattern. Now I have a View that implements *Editor* and a *Presenter* who gets the *EditorDriver* per getter access. The Presenter call *edit()* and *flush()* on the *EditorDriver*.

What I have found is a *MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver* but nothing like a *editormock*. A ready to use *"MockSimpleBeanEditor"* would be nice.

Is there any way to get that working in an JUnit test?

Answer (score 0):

A possible route for you to take is to 'fabricate' a mock editor.
The simplest and elegant way I can think of is Mockito.
Check this out::

```java
Comparable c = mock(Comparable.class);
when(c.compareTo("Test")).thenReturn(1);
assertEquals(1, c.compareTo("Test"));
```

This code snippet fabricates an instance of Comparable that will return '1' when passed the string 'Test'.

More info [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)